# Is it safe to run DBCC CLEANTABLE on a production database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, standard-edition

I recently changed an application from storing images in a varbinary(max) column to cloud storage and migrated the data and removed the column. These images accounted for about 350GB of space in the database.

I want to reclaim the space by running DBCC CLEANTABLE but I'm not clear on the affect it would have on a live database. If I give it a batch size instead of leaving it at 0, will running it cause deadlocks or other issues? This is a table that is still being used actively and I really don't have a long enough maintenance window to do this off hours.

Also, if running DBCC CELANTABLE with a batch size, canceling the query is almost immediate. What does canceling the query actually do?

Comment: Please tag with your edition and version of sql server.

Comment: @bbaird okay, updated.

Comment: According to the docs, batch size is per transaction, so locks are only held up to the end of the batch. Cancelling will only roll back the current batch, if that's big then it will take a while, if it's small it'll be quick